# How do i generate random password based on the month names?

Tags: php, random, passwords

I want to generate a random password based on the monthly names, the function should pick `alphabet` from the `A to Z` and place to the 5th position of the random password generated?

**Problem**

I'm a little bit confused about how do I pick the first letter of the `$alphabet` base on the `January` and place to the 5th position of the random password generated?

**For Example If Current Month Is January**

if the current month is January then the function should pick `A` from 
    the `$alphabet` and place to the 5th position of the random password 
    generated?

**For Example If Current Month Is February**

if the current month is February then the function should pick `B` from 
    the `$alphabet` and place to the 5th position of the random password 
    generated

**PHP CODE**

```
function randomPassword() {
$currentmonth = date('F');


if($currentmonth == 'January'){
$alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ";    
$random = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
$pass = array();    

     $alphaLength = strlen($random) - 1; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $pass[] = $random[$n];
    }

   return implode($pass); 

} 
}
echo randomPassword();
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to base it on monthly names? It makes it less random and more guessable. There ar far better ways to generate random strings than this.

Comment: @JohnConde because it is project requirements?

Comment: I'd generate 2 seperate ramdom strings, then concatanate them with the "a", "b",.. in the middle.

Comment: @Jeff example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this all you need to to is keep track of the month and use it to get the nth character of your `$alphabet` string. Then you can just replace the fifth element of your `$pass` array with it before you `implode()` the final password.

```
function randomPassword() {
    $currentmonth = date('n');
    $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ";    
    $random = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
    $pass = array();    

    $alphaLength = strlen($random) - 1; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
          $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
          $pass[] = $random[$n];
    }
    $pass[4] = substr($alphabet, $currentmonth - 1, 1);

    return implode($pass); 

}
echo randomPassword();
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/YHPUi)

Here's a more concise way to generate the random password:

```
function randomPassword() {
    $currentmonth = date('n') - 1;
    $alphabet = "abcdefghijklm";
    $random_hash = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 28, 4);
    return $random_hash . substr($alphabet, $currentmonth, 1);
}
echo randomPassword();
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/FWcka)

Keep in mind these passwords are short and pseudo-random and not very secure.

Comment: I have to try your code is showing like `fg1YYm` why last alpha `m`  it should `A`

Comment: Check again and view the demo

Comment: ok, it is working with `5th position` ok how about if the password is `15` character and I want to change `5th` and `10th` Position?

Comment: Here the requirement

5th character will be an alphabetic letter, remember this alphabet starts from A and will end at Z.
10th character of the password will also be an alphabet but in the reverse order, example: first month the letter will be Z
The last 15th  character will also be an alphabet but in the reverse order i.e. Z

Comment: I think my example shows you the concept of how to do that.

Comment: As you only want 1 char and the source is a string, you can treat it as an array and just use `$pass[4] = $alphabet[$currentmonth - 1];`